# how to declare public class

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I am so sorry for the question that sounds so stupid :)

I have such line of code:

```
namespace Messages{
/// @brief Interface to support building a message during decoding.
class ValueMessageBuilder : public Common::Logger
....
```

And I can not use `ValueMessageBuilder` from my c# project because of this error:

`Cannot access internal struct 'ValueMessageBuilder' here.`

So I've tried to make it public and recompile dll:

`public class ValueMessageBuilder : public Common::Logger`

But compilation failed with such error `Error C3381: 'QuickFAST::Messages::ValueMessageBuilder' : assembly access specifiers are only available in code compiled with a /clr option F:\Oleg\quickfast_1_4_0_my\src\Messages\ValueMessageBuilder.h   17  1   QuickF‌​AST`

So the question is how to convert internal `ValueMessageBuilder` structure to public?

Comment: Where are you trying to use it?

Comment: This isn't a C++ issue, rather a C#/CLR one.

Comment: Possibly this question asked on SO previously may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920844/c-sharp-how-to-access-internal-class-from-external-assembly

Answer (score 0):

As the error states your code must be compiled with /clr option (Project properties | General | Common Language Runtime Support). after that your project will become c++/clr (managed c++).
Also I think the class should be preceded with *ref* keyword to be visible in c#.

Comment: `/clr` is alredy set, and `ref` keyword doesn't work (see comment above)

Answer (score 0):

For a class to be usable from C#, it needs to be a managed type with .NET metadata.

Use either `ref class` or `value class`.

Note that an object can't contain both managed and native class types.  However, a native class can hold a handle to a managed instance (use `gcroot`) and a managed type can hold a pointer to a native object ([My smart pointer, posted on codereview, may help with lifetime management](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1695/scoped-ptr-for-c-cli-ensure-managed-object-properly-frees-owned-native-object)).

Comment: using `ref class` or `value class` i receive `this declaration has no storage class or type specified` error

Comment: @javapowered: It sounds like `/clr` isn't set on every single file that includes this header.

Comment: but i see `/clr` option in project properties, I don't know what else can I do...

Comment: @javapowered: There's compile options for the project, and also compile options for each individual compilation unit (same properties window, access it from the `.cpp` file).

Comment: it wouldn't be easy to check every possible file in the project

Comment: @javapowered: Start by checking the one being compiled when the error happens.  (Not the header, the .cpp that included it)