# Query set / internal value of Control.Visible

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a mechanism to read the value that is SET to the visible property of a control?

```
ChildControl1.Visible = true;
ChildControl2.Visible = false;

ParentControl.Visible = false;

bool childControl1Visible = ChildControl1.Visible
bool childControl2Visible = ChildControl2.Visible
```

In the example above, both childControl1Visible and childControl2Visible will return false as neither will be rendered due to the visibility of ParentControl.

I'm looking for a way to determine if a child control has itself been set to visible true/false regardless of the value set on any parent controls.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get the internal value - it's all kept inside an `internal` bit vector called `flags` ([see source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/UI/Control.cs#L1264)).

You would either have to manually track the visible property elsewhere or wrap the control in your own inherited class where you can override the `Visible` property and expose the value there. For example:

```
public class MyTextBox : System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
{
    public bool Visible
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Visible;
        }   
        set
        {
            ReallyVisible = value;
            vase.Visible = value;
        }
    }

    public bool ReallyVisible { get; private set; }
}
```

You may want to choose a better property name!

Another hacky way would be to use reflection to get access to the internal value. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/920868/1663001) for a method of doing that.